# Nginx fastcgi cache configuration

Tags: nginx

Here's the cache path configuration inside http{}

```
fastcgi_cache_methods   GET HEAD;
fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=website:10m inactive=1d max_size=10m;
```

Here's the config in virtualhost:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/manageraddons.socket;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_cache       website;
    fastcgi_cache_key         $host$uri$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_cache_valid       200 301 302 304 40s;
        fastcgi_cache_valid       any 5s;       
}
```

I create a simple php file, including the following lines:

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

So, my intention is: When I access it for the first time, it prints me the current time.
Since the page is now cached, the next time I try to access the page, should show me the older time, not the current. But every time I refresh the page, the content printed changes to.
I need stop nginx to send requests to fastcgi, how to properly configurate nginx to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't send any Cache-Control header!

Comment: I did, just forgot to mention that. Even still, that's no just for browser cache?

Comment: You should edit your question, then.

Comment: The phrase 'send `Cache-Control` header' is ambiguous; If sent by client, that will strip any caching effort from the server by default (typically `Cache-Control: "max-age=0"` when you hit `F5`). You can also make your backend sending it, but that should not be necessary since the provided configuration explicitely set some defaults with `fastcgi_cache_valid` (although sending those headers will override them).

Comment: Correcting my previous comment: the header sent by client on `F5` indicates the client does not wish cached content, but nginx by default does not take it into account (cf. [`fastcgi_cache_bypass`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_bypass)). @AndréStein check the configuration you loaded is right (`nginx -t`, checking error logs on reload signal, `nginx -T`), and you should log (or add as header) the [`$upstream_cache_status`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_cache_status) variable. Share a minimal conf if needed.